# Google Geolocation API - You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API

Tags: php, web-services, google-api, geocoding, google-geolocation

I'm trying to get the latitude and the longitude values for an specific place in a webservice query, but when I try to get it, I get this error_message

> "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. If you did not set a custom daily request quota, verify your project has an active billing account: http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account [results]".

My problem is that I have and API key and I added it to my query. On my project's console, I've added the geo location API and copied my API key. Here my query:

```
$url = 'https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key={mykey}&address=%22' . $city . '%22&sensor=true';
```

I don't know which could be the problem, because the error_message says `"... maps-no-account"` but I have my API key, then I suppose that the API key is related with my account, but it seems not working. If  Any idea?

If it's not possible to do it with Google without paying quote, is there any other useful and free tool for my purpose?

Comment: https://tech.yandex.com/maps/mapsapi

Comment: Thanks! I've been able to use this web page to be able to query what I needed. It's been very useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is quite clear.

- you have exceded your daily request quota for this api.

You are allowed to make some requests and you have used those requests up.

- verify billing is active on your account.

The Geolocation api is not a free api you must pay to use it [usage and billing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing) check that your billing account has been probably set up for the developer account which created your api key.

Comment: I wonder why it could be that, because I had only been able to make a query. Also, in the error message, it gives me to understand that I am not using any user, which is false. I was also looking for an alternative, but I have already found it, I will use the tech.yandex.com/maps/mapsapi website. Anyway, thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: The api key is a user.    As far as i know there is no free quota for that api you need to enable billing before its going to work at all.   Please remember to accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: @DaImTo What about 200$ monthly free quotes ?

Comment: I dont know of any $200 a month free quota sorry.  I know when you first create your Google developer account they give you a single $200 try out money but thats not something that your going to get every month.  You still have to set up a billing account to use it.   Including adding your credit card info.